# How can I show a div at bottom of google map?

Tags: google-maps

I am using google map , which has some height almost to window height . I want to place a div below that map which has some dynamic data .

When I am trying to do this , I get div at bottom of map but the content of div gets hide . I want the scroll bar in window when the content of div goes above window height .
How I can do this , please help me .
I am using following code :

```
<div id="map-canvas" style="width:100%; height:600px"></div>
<div>here the dynamic table will be generated ...</div>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try with the position attribute of the div.

```
position: absolute
```

or

```
position: relative
```

Also you can use the developer option in chrome or mozilla(Ctrl+Shift+I) to postion your div properly.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add position: relative; to map-canvas and position: absolute; to div;

```
<div style="position: absolute">here the dynamic table will be generated ...</div>
```